# How do I get HTML inside Spacebars {{if}} to change reactively with a Session variable?

Tags: javascript, meteor, spacebars

In my Meteor project, I want a template section to be displayed according to a `Session` variable; however, the HTML inside the `{{#if}}` is not appearing reactively.
How do I get `{{#if}}{{/if}}` to change reactively with a session variable?

HTML:

```
<head>
  <title>testApp</title>
</head>
<body>
  {{> testTemplate}}
</body>

<template name="testTemplate">
  {{#if isDisplayed}}
    <div>It's working!</div>
  {{/if}}
  <button id="testButton">Toggle Display</button>
</template>
```

JavaScript:

```
Session.setDefault("displayVar", false);

Template.testTemplate.helpers({
    isDisplayed: Session.get("displayVar")
});

Template.testTemplate.events({
    "click #testButton": function () {
        if (Session.get("displayVar")) {
            Session.set("displayVar", false);
        } else {
            Session.set("displayVar", true);
        };
    }
});
```

Comment: Note that in your event code you could be more simple by writing only `Session.set('displayVar', !Session.get('displayVar'))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning a helper as a value:

```
isDisplayed : Session.get('displayVar')
```

Is the same as doing:

```
isDisplayed: false // or true, or whatever 'displayVar' is when run
```

To solve this simply use a function (here, an ES6 [Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) since Meteor uses Babel):

```
isDisplayed: () => Session.get('displayVar')
```

Using a function makes sure that a [`Tracker`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker) computation is generated.

Answer (score 0):

Your helper needs to *return* the value from an anonymous function:

```
Template.testTemplate.helpers({
  isDisplayed: function(){
    return Session.get("displayVar");
  }
});
```